# Creating Dynamic Lambda Expression To Pivot Table

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda

I'm working on a shift scheduler for work. The desired layout is as follows:

```
    | Employee1   |  Employee2   |  Employee3   |  etc...
----------------------------------------------------------
Mon | Shift_Type1 |  Shift_Type2 |  Shift_Type3 |  etc...
Tue | Shift_Type3 |  Shift_Type2 |  Shift_Type1 |  etc...
```

Now, I've been able to come up with a LINQ query that works, but it's hard-coded.

```
var dataSource = db.Shifts
            .GroupBy(key => key.Date.Value)
            .Select(shift => new
                {
                    Date = shift.Key,
                    Employee1 = shift.Where(s => s.Employee_ID == "xxxXxx").Max(s => s.Shift_Type.Name)
            });
        GridView_OverView.DataSource = dataSource;
        GridView_OverView.DataBind();
        db.Dispose();
```

I want to be able to call the date column, and then for each employee I have in db.Employees, I want to create a new section of this in the select statement.

```
EmployeeX = shift.Where(s => s.Employee_ID == "xxxXxx").Max(s => s.Shift_Type.Name)
```

I read up a little on expression trees [here in this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx), and I tried to put one together myself. However, it comes up with an error whenever I try to run it.

```
List<System.Data.Linq.Table<Shift>> results = null;
        ParameterExpression parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Shift), "s");

        foreach (Employee employee in db.Employees)
        {

            // s.Employee_ID == "xxxXxx"
            Expression left = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "Employee_ID");
            Expression right = Expression.Constant(employee.ID_UserName);
            Expression predicateBody1 = Expression.Equal(left, right);

            // s.Shift_Type.Name
            Expression predicateBody2 = Expression.Property(Expression.Property(parameterExpression, "Shift_Type"), "Name");

            // Where(s => s.Employee_ID == "xxxXxx")
            MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Where",
                new Type[] { db.Shifts.AsQueryable().ElementType },
                db.Shifts.AsQueryable().Expression,
                Expression.Lambda<Func<Shift, bool>>(predicateBody1, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression })
                );

            // .Max(s => s.Shift_Type.Name)
            MethodCallExpression maxCallExpression = Expression.Call(
                typeof(Queryable),
                "Max",
                new Type[] { db.Shifts.AsQueryable().ElementType },
                whereCallExpression,
                Expression.Lambda<Func<Shift, bool>>(predicateBody2, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExpression })
                );

            results.AddRange(db.Shifts.AsQueryable().Provider.CreateQuery<System.Data.Linq.Table<Shift>>(maxCallExpression).ToList());
        }
```

The error is a System.ArgumentException, which happens in the maxCallExpression.

Additional Informaton: An expression of type 'System.String' can not be used for the return type 'System.Boolean'

I've been stuck here for a while, and I'm not sure what to do to fix this. I can't find any documentation on running the max expression, and I don't know what the parameters need to be like. Any help would be greatly appreciated.